# Using template inline in Jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'd like to pass the name of a template file to my jade template and have it expand that template. I'm using node and express.

```
html
  div(id="content")
    extend #(content}
```

seems intuitive to me but it doesn't work. Is this possible and/or is there an alternative pattern to better achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

After rethinking the pattern (I'm brand new to express and node), I realized a better solution. What I've done is taken the content (which was all static) and included it in block statements in multiple template files. I then serve those template files based on the route.

Say I have a layout page that has header and footer and multiple views: index, search, and getting started.

```
//layout.jade
  html
    head
     block extra_headers
    body
     div(id="header")
     div(id="content")
       block content
     div(id="footer")
```

---

```
//index.jade
  html
    block head
      script(src="sss.js")
    block content
      | welcome to my home page
```

---

```
//results.jade
html
  block head
    script(src="search.js")
  block content
    | my search results
```

And so on with 'getting started'. My node code then looks like this:

```
app.get('/', function(res, req) {
  return res.render('index'); // renders the index view.
});
```